# How can I show content when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show an image when I click on the button. But right now the button hides the image when I click on it. Is there a way to reverse this? This is the code I have.

```js
var flag = 1;

function coursework() {
  if (flag == 1) {
    document.getElementsById("coursework").style.display = "none";
    flag = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("coursework").style.display = "block";
    flag = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="coursework()">Show Coursework</button>
<div id="coursework">
  <img src="Wellcome.png" width="300">
</div>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean you want the page to start with the image hidden?

Comment: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: swap `none` and `block`. This will do that for yo

Comment: This already works, all you need to do is what @UsmanRana said: change `getElementsById` to `getElementByid`.

Comment: Just an idea: you may want to toggle a class name instead of `display` property. This way you separate styling from logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image to `display: none;` initially and then change your `if-else` condition accordingly so that the image is displayed on first click and hide on second click and so on. Also, it should be `getElementById` and not `getElementsById`.

```js
document.getElementById("coursework").style.display="none";
var flag =1;
  function coursework() {
    if(flag==1)
    {
      document.getElementById("coursework").style.display="block"; 
      flag=0;
    }
  else{
    document.getElementById("coursework").style.display="none"; 
    flag=1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="coursework()">Show Coursework</button>
<div id="coursework">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/87840/daisy-pollen-flower-nature-87840.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" width="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assume scenario that initially you hide image and when click on button it will show it, may be it will different from what you want and try to give this answer. Refer following code

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="show()">Show Coursework</button>
<div id="coursework" style="display:none">
<img src="welcome.png" width="300">
</div>

<script>
function show(){
   document.getElementById("coursework").style.display="block"; 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this will help full.